# Como inserir com conteúdo maior que a tela?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Como colocar mais conteúdo pelo storyboard em uma tela de iPhone sem os problemas de limites da tela. 
 Por exemplo: tenho uma tela onde preciso colocar um `UIImageView` e outro `UITextView` duas vezes um abaixo do outro. Mas não quero usar tabela, simplesmente so colocar um abaixo do outro.
 Como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema que a visualização de tela do `Storyboard` limita o manuseio, como eu poderia contornar esse problema?

Comment: Acho que achei a solução para mim deu certo!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905568/how-do-i-use-uiscrollview-in-storyboard

Comment: Tiago, vi que você está fazendo progressos no iOS. Você já usou o PhoneGap? https://build.phonegap.com/

Comment: Sim ja vi algumas coisas mas eu sempre prefiro fazer a coisa nativa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um componente que chama **scrollview** que você pode colocar UIImageView e UITextView dentro do mesmo, assim sua tela no Iphone vai poder deslizar para cima e para baixo, mostrando todo o conteúdo. Talvez isso possa ajudar na sua dúvida.

Comment: Sim ja estou usando este componente e meajudou perfeitamente! Obrigado @LuizTeodoroJunior